# JoinMulticastGroup thrown invalid argument exception?

Tags: c#, multicast

I am using following piece of code in a program which sends udp multicast packets,

But I get the exception at the very start

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UdpClient udpclient = new UdpClient();

        IPAddress multicastaddress = IPAddress.Parse("239.0.0.222");   

       // Here I get System.Net.Sockets.SocketException , An invalid argument was supplied
        udpclient.JoinMulticastGroup(multicastaddress);

        ...
```

The mahcine where I have this problem is windows xp. When I run the same code on another machine (windows 7) I do not get this exception, any ideas what could be wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a workaround, I've the exact same problem when creating a socket with a multicast option

Answer (score 2):

To avoid socket error 10048:

Try:

```
UdpClient udpclient = new UdpClient();
IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, _listenPort);
udpclient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
udpclient.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
udpclient.Client.Bind(ipEndPoint);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a port to the udpclient like

```
udpClient = new udpClient(9000) //or IPEndPoint with IPAddress and Port
```

anyways dealing with microsofts udpclient is quiet painfully

Comment: Does this really fix the problem? or does it fix a different problem?

Comment: It solves the problem because the client needs a port to listen not only an address.

Comment: Hello ,I am facing the same problem, but the above Solution is not work on my side, Please help....